# How exists clause work with null in nested query?

Tags: sql

As per sql server, Null is not equivalent to any thing in sql but following queries returns all the products for which order has been placed.

```
Select * from products 
where exists (select null from orderdetails 
where orderdetails.product_id = products.product_id
```

Comment: The behavior can be toggled to in SQLServer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(SQL.80).aspx. In ANSI SQL NULL = NULL returns false, as does NULL <> NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) test for existence of rows. It does not check the values. You could use `where exists (select * ...)` or `where exists(select 1 ...)`. It would not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

`Exists` tests to see if the statement contained returns any rows.

We'll follow this through step by step.

---

```
select null from orderdetails 
where orderdetails.product_id = products.product_id
```

Return a row containing `null` for each order in the orderdetails table with a given product_id.

---

```
exists (select null from orderdetails 
where orderdetails.product_id = products.product_id)
```

Return true if the subquery returns any rows (if there are orders in the table with that product_id, we will have rows containing `null`)

---

```
Select * from products 
where exists (select null from orderdetails 
where orderdetails.product_id = products.product_id)
```

Return every product where there exists any orders in the orderdetail table.

Answer (score 1):

The `exists` clause checks for existence: whether the sub query returns *any* data. It does not worry about the data itself.

`exists` is true if the sub query returns *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

> Exists Returns TRUE if a subquery contains any rows.

what you are doing is Select Null; this will return a row of null  and thus the condition will be true

Answer (score 0):

Try, instead of `select null`, selecting the id, primary key.