# sql query to link two tables

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, sql-server-2000

I have a table called users where the employee data are stored.
Also I have another table payment_details where employee's payment related data are stored 
the two tables are as follows.

this table is **users**

```
sr_no  emp_no  username  payment

1     1001      leroy    <null>
2     1003      harry    <null>
3     1004      Tom      <null>   
4     1008      Jon      <null>
```

This table below  is **payment_details**

```
    sr_no       name     number      month    status        date
      43        Jon       1008       January  paid         5/16/2012
      44        Jon       1008       January  balance      5/16/2012
      45        Harry     1003       January  paid         5/16/2012
      46        Tom       1004       January  paid         5/16/2012
      47        leroy     1001       January  paid         5/16/2012
      48        Jon       1008       January  paid         5/16/2012
      49        Harry     1003       January  paid         5/16/2012
      50        Jon       1008       February balance      5/16/2012
      51        leroy     1001       February paid         5/16/2012
      52        Jon       1008       February paid         5/16/2012
      53        Tom       1004       February balance      5/16/2012
```

My question here is to update "users" table **payment** column to "paid" when the status of his/her is all **paid** in **payment_details** table

Comment: And what do you expect as result ? (The Answer depends on it :)

Comment: can you give us the column names for ayment_details. And yes what you whan't from us?

Comment: You should try your query by using JOIN . But, I think you should change your table design.

Comment: By the looks of it, `sr_no` in the `users` table isn't related to `sr_no` in the `payment_details` table - that's terrible design!

Comment: @bridge I'm nt concerned with the sr_no....i have set the identity to increment by "1"....

Comment: @Mckenzi I was going to presume you could join the two tables as part of the answer; normally you would expect the two columns with the same name in each would match but here they don't. I'm guessing `Emp_No` in 'users' corresponds to `number` in `payment_details` and that should be used for joining instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db13f/18

```
update users set payment = 'paid'
from
(
  select number
  from payment_details
  group by number
  having sum(case when status = 'paid' then 1 end) 
       = count(*)
) as x
where x.number = users.emp_no;
```

Or this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db13f/19

```
update users
  set payment = x.upd
from 
(
  select u.emp_no, 

      case when sum(case when d.status = 'paid' then 1 end)  = count(*) then
         'paid'
      else
         null
      end as upd

  from users u

  left join payment_details d
  on d.number = u.emp_no

  group by u.emp_no
) as x
where x.emp_no = users.emp_no;
```

Their difference is how many rows it updates. On the second query, it updates all users, regardless if the user has a paid all status(`'paid'`) or not(`null`); on the first query, it updates only those who are paid.

The advantage of the second query, is when you change one of the all `'paid'` `status` on `payment_detail` of a given user to 'not paid' for example, it can revert back the user's `payment` status to `null`

Comment: thank you @Michael ..I think the second method looks interesting...but how can I use it with my asp code where I'm updating payment_details table on button click .....the code i'm using is `<% if request.form("sub1") <> "" then sql="select * from payment_details" rs.open sql,con,1,2 rs.addnew rs("name") = session("name") rs("number") = session("No") rs("month")= request.form("chk1") rs("status")= request.form("r") rs("date") = date() rs.update response.write("<script language='javascript'>{update1();}</script>") rs.close end if %>

Comment: Just put it in stored proc or function, then call it in your code. It look brittle embedding long query in code, especially you're using asp classic, you have to concatenate very long string

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE order_details
SET payment= 'paid'
WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM payment_details 
              WHERE payment_details.emp_no= order_details.emp_no
              AND   payment_details.status <> 'paid'
             )
```

Comment: what does select "1" mean what exactly it is doing..??

Comment: Exists check for records count of inner queries, so you can use Null,1,field ..etc  with Select in inner query. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436166/how-exists-clause-work-with-null-in-nested-query

Comment: also one more issue now....I'm using vbscript and ADO I'm nt sure it'll work as the query that I'm using to update payment_details is completely different..

Comment: This query is written perfectly for ADO.

Comment: this is the query that I'm passing on the button click in my form and it updates the payment_details table                                          ` <%
     if request.form("sub1") <> "" then
     sql="select * from payment_details"
     rs.open sql,con,1,2
     rs.addnew
     
     rs("name") = session("name")
     rs("number") = session("No")
     rs("month")= request.form("chk1")
     rs("status")= request.form("r")
     rs("date") = date()
     rs.update
     response.write("<script language='javascript'>{update1();}</script>")
     
     rs.close
     end if
    %>`

Comment: @Mckenzi, if you press the "help" button it tells you how. Surround it in the ` character.

Answer (score 0):

There also simple way to get the value of particulars table into variable and update the tabe as below:

```
declare @bb varchar(50)
select @bb= status from payment_details where name=@name and id=@id
update uuser set payment = @bb
where name = @name and id=@id
```